# how to use a custom function in query on Spark Dataframe using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I load data from database to Spark Dataframe,named **DF**,then I must to extract some records from the Dataframe which their ID has special condition. So, I define this function:

```
def hash_id(id:String): Int = {
val two_char = id.takeRight(2).toInt
val hash_result = two_char % 4
return hash_result
 }
```

Then, I use the function in this query:

```
DF.filter(hash_id("ID")===3)
```

But I receive this error:

```
value === is not a member of Int
```

**DF** has **ID** column.

Would you please guide me how to use a custom function in `where/filter` clause?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`===` can only be used between Column objects. That's why you have an error `value === is not a member of Int`, as return type of your function `hash_id` is an `Int`, not a `Column`

To be able to use your function, you should convert it to an [user-defined function](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-udf/) and apply this function to a column object as follow:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}

def hash_id(id:String): Int = {
  val two_char = id.takeRight(2).toInt
  val hash_result = two_char % 4
  return hash_result
}

val hash_id_udf = udf((id: String) => hasd_id(id))

DF.filter(hash_id_udf(col("ID")) === 3)
```